# Adding a second datasource - SpringBoot RepositoryRestService PersistenceConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find the best approach to adding a second datasource to our application. The main purpose is to expose CRUD ops against the db via rest, & need to bounce against a 2nd db for authentication and role management. We are not using XML configs.

Is there a way to simply add a second datasource bean in the existing PersistenceConfig.java file, or do we need to replicate the whole config class for the second db instance?

The application:

package foo;

```
import foo.config.PersistenceConfig;
import foo.config.RepositoryRestConfig;
import foo.config.WebConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import({PersistenceConfig.class, WebConfig.class, RepositoryRestConfig.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Repo:

```
package foo.repository;

import foo.Widget;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.List;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "widgets", path = "widgets")
public interface WidgetsRepository extends CrudRepository<Widget, Long> {
    List<Widget> findByWidgetId(@Param("widgetid") long widgetId);
}
```

The persistence config :

```
package foo.config;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("foo.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=fooDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("*******");
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(true);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1800000L);
        dataSource.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1800000L);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new HibernateJpaDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your assistance...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `@Qualifier` annotation. With this annotation you are able to define various beans of the same type and assign them names. It is equivalent of `id` parameter in `bean` XML tag.

This is [relevant part of Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's worth noting that almost all of the configuration in `PersistenceConfig` is redundant as Spring Boot will automatically configure it for you. Pretty much the only thing that is non-default and you need to specify is your DataSource configuration, for example the SQLServer URL.

There's a [section in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) that describes how to configure two DataSources using `@Primary` and `application.properties`:

> Creating more than one data source works the same as creating the first one. You might want to mark one of them as @Primary if you are using the default auto-configuration for JDBC or JPA (then that one will be picked up by any @Autowired injections)."

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

You'd then configure these two DataSources using `application.properties` and the `datasource.primary` and `datasource.secondary` prefixes:

For example:

```
datasource.primary.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=fooDB
datasource.primary.user=sa
datasource.primary.password=secret

datasource.primary.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=barDB
datasource.primary.user=sa
datasource.primary.password=secret
```

Comment: But you didn't explain how to use the secondary for a concrete repository CrudRepository. With this you have two datasource, but you always use the Primary.