# How to set a specific DataSource for a Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to assign a specific `DataSource` to a `@Repository`?

I'd like to create a test environment where in general I want to use the test-datasource, but a few `CrudRepository` should operate on a different DB (the production DB; read-only operations).

Can I tell spring which datasource to use for a repository explicit?

`public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {}`

Comment: See if this will work http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-two-entity-managers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`@EnableJpaRepositories` is the answer to your question. This should work with `CrudRepository` according to the informal documentations.

Refer this detail tutorial on how to do this. I didn't put my effort to post the codes here as you may directly refer it much clearer in it.

[link to the Tutorial...](https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-jpa-and-multiple-projects/)

Answer (score 7):

The `DataSource` and `JpaRepository` are both tied to an `EntityManager`.  You will have to segregate the repositories into separate packages for your requirement to work.

Here is an example:

```
<bean id="emf1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
    <bean .../>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.example.package1" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf1"/>

<bean id="emf2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
    <bean .../>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.example.package2" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on which is your design , cause there are different implementations that you can follow , f.e you can declare two beans for the two datasources and in your code specify to which one you want to hit , or else you could define two differents context and a shared context in which again you ll have to specify in your code which service you want to call.
Here is an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703295/adding-a-second-datasource-springboot-repositoryrestservice-persistenceconfig) that might help you for the 1st approach

Answer (score -1):

Just set the `name` attribute of the `@PersistenceContext` annotation when declaring your `EntityManager`.

```
@PersistenceContext(name="persistence-unit-name")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: i feel like this is the correct answer, just missing some important details

Answer (score -3):

Try to declare the required DataSource `@Bean` or  explicitly as `@Primary`.