# How to choose which Datasource to use when @Autowiring with Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, autowired

I have a Spring-boot application with 2 Datasources.

> application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data1
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.secondDatasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data2
spring.secondDatasource.username=root
spring.secondDatasource.password=pass


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

> DataBaseConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
         return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean   
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

> MessageRepository.java

```
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>{

}
```

> MessageController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messages")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired  
    private MessageRepository repositoryPostGreSQL;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPosta(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("messages", repositoryPostGreSQL.findAll());
        return "messages/list";
    }
}
```

It is working fine, the 2 Databases are connected and working.

What I need to know is that when I `@Autowire` a `Repository` how do I specify witch `DataSource` should be linked?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to with `Repository`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added the code

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397522/how-to-set-a-specific-datasource-for-a-repository).