# Springboot HikariCP was not used

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

It seems Hikaricp was not used.

For example, spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size is always effected.
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size is not affected.

I set the following:

```
in application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
      ....
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      hikari:
          connection-timeout: 60000
          maximum-pool-size: 5
```

And then I checked the number of connection by netstat command.
There ware 10 connections. 
It seems that maximum-pool-size of hikari doesn't work.
Even if I deleted  the spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size, the
maximum-pool-size of hikari still doesn't work.

Moreover, I set the follwoing log event, but there were no log about HikariCP.

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: NOTE
    org.springframework: DEBUG
```

Of course, I built with the follwoing dependencies to make sure it exculded tomcat-jdbc:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {

exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc") {

exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}
compile("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.0")
```

Could you help to how to find the problem?

Comment: You probably don't use it, how does your code get its datasource, it should contain HikariDataSource

Comment: I developed "public interface sampleRepository extends CrudRepository<xx,yy>" to access Postgrage. It works. But It doesn't use HikaraCP for me. Am I wrong?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397522/how-to-set-a-specific-datasource-for-a-repository

Comment: Thank you for your help. I check the questions, but I couldn't understand. I would like to handle a DataSource of HikariCP. I don't want to use the other. I'm sorry for asking some silly questions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in my spring boot app which needed two database connections.

Here are my Configuration beans:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.primary")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourcePropertiesPrimary() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.primary.hikari")
public HikariDataSource dataSourcePrimary() {
    return dataSourcePropertiesPrimary()
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}
```

And my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.primary.hikari.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.primary.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3
```

You can use Jolokia to confirm before and after the pool size.

Alternatively you can confirm by running your app in debug mode and break pointing the file `HikariConfig.java` on the private method `validateNumerics` where `maxPoolSize` is set.